# how to apply array to view

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am doing array sorting. but i am not getting how do i apply this sorted array in view and give proper ui. here is my array sorting code. on click i am able to sort the result but it only shows array values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function sort(key) {
    var sortTypes = {
            alpha: function (a, b) { return a[key].localeCompare(b[key]); },
            numerical: function (a, b) { return a[key] - b[key]; }
        },
        keys = {
            rateType: 'alpha',
            interestRateMin: 'numerical',
            financingPercentageMax: 'numerical',
            interestRateMax: 'numerical',
            financingPercentageMin: 'numerical',
            bankName: 'alpha',
            repaymentTenureInYears: 'numerical',
            age: 'numerical',
            maxLoanAmt: 'numerical',
        };

    return sortTypes[keys[key]];
}

var data = <?php echo json_encode($json['resultList']); ?>;

document.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var select = document.getElementById('sort-by'),
        index = select.selectedIndex,
        key = select.options[index].value

    data.sort(sort(key));
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4);
});

</script>
```

PHP code which generates web services in proper ui

```
<div id="out">
      <?php if(count($json['resultList']) > 0): ?>
      <?php 
        foreach ($json['resultList'] as $key=>$value) {
            if($json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"] == $json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMax"]){
                $interest = $json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"];
            }
            else{
                $interest = $json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"].' - '.$json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMax"];

}

            if($json["resultList"][$key]["financingPercentageMin"] == $json["resultList"][$key]["financingPercentageMax"]){
                $financing = $json["resultList"][$key]["financingPercentageMin"];
            }
            else{
                $financing = $json["resultList"][$key]["financingPercentageMin"].' - '.$json["resultList"][$key]["financingPercentageMax"];

}

                echo '
  <div class="cr-content">                
                <div class="bank-rates">
      <ul>
   <li>
   <div class="innr-spl" style="padding: 5px 0;">
          <span style="display:block;"><img src="'.$json["resultList"][$key]["imageUrl"].'"></span>
   <span class="hide">'.$json["resultList"][$key]["bankName"].'</span>
   </div>
   </li>

 <li><div class="innr-spl2">' . $interest . '%' . '</div></li>
 <li><div class="innr-spl2">' . $financing  . '</div></li>
   <li class="hide"><div class="innr-spl3 kmore" id="'.$key.'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>View Datails</div> </li>
        <li>
        <div class="apply-now innr-spl"><a href="http://www.zengalol.com/gold-loan/" type="button" role="button" target="_blank" class="btn-apply">Apply Now</a></div>
        </li>      
      </ul>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>

      <ul class="details" id="ban_'.$key.'" style = "display:none;">
        <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Maximum Loan Amount : '.$json["resultList"][$key]["maxLoanAmt"].'</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Max Tenure (In Years) : '.$json["resultList"][$key]["repaymentTenureInYears"].'</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Interest Rate Type : '.$json["resultList"][$key]["rateType"].'</li>    
      </ul>

    </div>
    </div>

                ';
                $i++;
        }


    ?>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by propar ui?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add html. Not only JSON-string.

for example:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
var html = '<ul><li>'+data.join("</li> <li>")+'</li></ul>';
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = html;
```

I'm not sure, if you are able to copy my code example. But probably not, because I don't want to write your huge html-code of your list into my example. But you can use that as a hint.

Comment: can you explain me little more.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? In general, you just have to add HTML-Code to your page, not only a json-string, because this is for the browser what it is. Just a string. And so all the html-tags (div, ul, li, ...) and css-classes are missing. Your task is now to put all the values of your sorted JSON-Array into a html-structure, which you can add to your document.

Comment: U have first parsed data and used that in variable Html. i didn't get +data.join. Do i have to parse each and every element which i want to display

Comment: data.join() -function just writes the values in a string and between every string it writes </li> <li>. In this way I have valid html for a select-box. You have to do a little bit more now. Go through your sorted values and add the html you need for every list-element. At the end I have to answer with Yes, you have to parse each element, wrap it with the html you need and add it to your document.

Comment: var html = '<div class="cr-content"><div class="bank-rates"><ul><li><div class="innr-spl" style="padding: 5px 0;"><span style="display:block;">' + imageUrl.join('</span><span class="hide">') + bankName.join('</span></div></li><li>') + '</div></li></ul>' ; is this the correct way?

Comment: You are on the right way, but this code will not work for you. Go trough your data-array and create something like this html = html + '<div class="cr-content"><div class="bank-rates"><ul><li><div class="innr-spl" style="padding: 5px 0;"><span style="display:block;">' +'<span class="hide">'+data.imageurl+'</span>' + '<span class="hide">'+data.bankName+'</span>'  + '</div></li></ul></div>